# drawImage() in Java, why isn't the image loading?

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have added the image in the src and bin directories and cross-checked that the name of the image file is correct

Here is the main class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class apples
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        MyDrawPanel wid = new MyDrawPanel();
        frame.add(wid);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
    }
}
```

and here is the class that does the image adding part

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel 
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        Image image = new ImageIcon("b.png").getImage();
        g.drawImage(image,20, 20, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding @Override before your overriden method, your IDE should alert you is it is not overriden (due to typo, ...). Also call `super.paintComponent(g)` unless you have good reason not to.

Comment: An instance of `MyDrawPanel` will have preferred size of 0x0 pixels. Your image is drawn outside of its bounding rect.

Comment: For better performance, do not make a `new ImageIcon("b.png")` in `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, create an `Image` attribute in `MyDrawPanel`

Comment: You can also read this tutorial: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/painting/ , or any other.

Comment: Hopefully this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), be able to help in this direction somewhat, especially the last link, if you doing it manually :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. `frame.setVisible(true);` should be last code line inside `public static void main(String args[])`, because you `setSize` to already visible `JFrame` (just torso contains only `Toolbar` with three `Buttons`)
2. every Swing code lines in `public static void main(String args[])` should be wrapped into `invokeLater()`, more info about in [Oracle tutorial Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
3. `public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel` returns zero `Dimension (0, 0)` you have to override `getPreferredSize` for (inside) `MyDrawPanel extends JPanel`, use there `new Dimension (300, 300)` from `frame.setSize(300,300);` and then replace this code line (`frame.setSize(300,300);`) with `frame.pack()`
4. `Image image = new ImageIcon("b.png").getImage();`

   a) don't to load any `FileIO` inside `paintComponent`, create this `Object` as local variable

   b) 1st code line inside `paintComponent` should be `super.paintComponent()` and without reason to be public, but protected (`public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`)

   c) `Dimension` set in `g.drawImage(image,20, 20, this);` doesn't corresponding with `frame.setSize(300,300);`, for why reason is there empty space

   d) most important (as mentioned in comments) `Image image = new ImageIcon("b.png").getImage();` isn't valid Java path

Answer (score 0):

try to use getClass().getResource("b.png"); instead of simply giving the file name.
Because it sometimes doesn't receive the image, so extract the path and resource.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your image (or any file) in the main project file when you work with eclipse  or other frameworks
and if you decides to specialize a specific folder in the project -to hold images for example- you can write `Image image = new ImageIcon("src\\b.png").getImage();//replace the src with folder name`

Or add the full (absolute)path

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a JFrame called frame and correctly declaring a class that inherits from Panel that can be drawn upon. The method `paintComponent(Graphics G)` in `MyDrawPanel.Java` is called upon every time the image needs to be rewritten.

I tested out your code in my own IDE and it works for me. I think that, as others also have suggested, that your picture needs to be dragged into your Eclipse IDE. Just drag-and-drop it into your Java-project.